# New on coding: How can I make that if the radioButton is not checked it says it's not so you cant complete the process of creating an object:

Tags: java, android

So I have an object with some fields (Two edit text and a radiogroup with two radiobuttons) and I need them all to be completed to create the object, I have all done except the gender (masculino-femenino down boolean down there coming from a from radiobutton). Everything works but the radioButton, How can I know they're empty, I'm running out of logic ideas and I know it have to ve something easy for this, probably obious This is what I have:

````
      ```
      public boolean camposCompletos() {
      if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
      } else if (desc.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
      }else if (masculino.isChecked() || femenino.isChecked()) {
                sexo_comprobacion = false;
                return false;
        }
      return true;
      }
      ```
````

Comment: you are using radio group?

Comment: set a default value, that way it's never null

Comment: Yes, I'ts a radiogroup. How do I set default? I'm pretty new on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code it will help you.

```
 //activity xml
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/male"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Male" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/female"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Female" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click" /> </LinearLayout>



  //activity code
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RadioButton maleRB, femaleRB;
private Button button;
private String selectedOption = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    maleRB = findViewById(R.id.male);
    femaleRB = findViewById(R.id.female);
    button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (maleRB.isChecked()) selectedOption = maleRB.getText().toString();
            if (femaleRB.isChecked()) selectedOption = femaleRB.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,selectedOption,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it too, it looks faster than my solution for some other points! by the way I fixed it in a obious way after a pause of resting my mind (I let it here in case it's usefull for someone):

```
public boolean camposCompletos() {
        if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else if (desc.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else if (!masculino.isChecked() && !femenino.isChecked()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```